# python boolean array pointer behavior

Tags: python, arrays, pointers

Are booleans made pointers?
I had this weird case:

```
visited = [[False]*4]*4
visited[0][1] = True
print visited
>>> [[False, True, False, False], [False, True, False, False], [False, True, False, False], [False, True, False, False]]
```

How do I avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been asked many, many times before. In fact, it is probably among the most frequently asked Python questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when you do `[[False]*4]*4`, you're creating a list of `[False,False,False,False]`, and then making four references to that exact same list instead of four copies. You may have to use a `for` loop or a list comprehension to avoid this happening.

```
visited = []
for i in range(4):
  falselist = [False]*4
  visited.append(falselist)
```